# setting a gdb exit breakpoint not working?

Tags: linux, unix, gdb

I've set breakpoints on exit and _exit and my program (multithreaded app, running on linux 2.6.16.46-0.12 sles10), is somehow still exiting in a way I can't locate

```
(gdb) c
...
[New Thread 47513671297344 (LWP 15279)]
[New Thread 47513667103040 (LWP 15280)]
[New Thread 47513662908736 (LWP 15281)]

Program exited with code 0177.
(gdb)
```

the exit functions reside in libc so there's no deferred load shared library issues.  Anybody know of some other mysterious trigger for exit that can't be caught?

EDIT: the problem is now academic only.  I tried binary search debugging, backing out a subset of my changes (the problem went away).  After I applied them again in sequence, I can no longer repro the problem, even with things restored to the original state.

EDIT2: I found one reason for this sort of error recently, which may have been the original source for this problem.  For historical reasons our product uses the evil linker flag -Bsymbolic.  Among the side effects of this is that when a symbol is undefined but called, the GLIBC runtime linker will bomb in exactly this way, and you see it in the debugger as a process exited with 0177.  When the runtime linker aborts this way, I'd guess it makes the syscall to _exit directly (rather than using the C runtime library exit() or _exit()).  That would be consistent with the fact that I was unable to catch this with an the exit breakpoints in the debugger.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There are two common reasons for `_exit` breakpoint to "miss" -- either `GDB` didn't set the breakpoint in the right place, or the program performs (a moral equivalent of) `syscall(SYS_exit, ...)`

What do `info break` and `disassemble _exit` say?

You might be able to convince `GDB` to set the breakpoint correctly with `break *&_exit`. Alternatively, `GDB-7.0` supports `catch syscall`. Something like this should work (assuming `Linux/x86_64`; note that on `ix86` the numbers will be different) regardless of how the program exits:

```
(gdb) catch syscall 60
Catchpoint 3 (syscall 'exit' [60])
(gdb) catch syscall 231
Catchpoint 4 (syscall 'exit_group' [231])
(gdb) c

Catchpoint 4 (call to syscall 'exit_group'), 0x00007ffff7912f3d in _exit () from /lib/libc.so.6
```

Update:
Your comment indicates that _exit breakpoint is set correctly, so it's likely that your process just doesn't execute `_exit`.

That leaves `syscall(SYS_exit, ...)` and one other possibility (which I missed before): all threads executing `pthread_exit`. You might want to set a breakpoint on `pthread_exit` as well (and execute `info thread` each time you hit it -- the last thread to do `pthread_exit` will cause the process to terminate).

**Edit:**

Also worth noting that you can use mnemonic names, rather than syscall numbers. You can also simultaneously add multiple syscalls to the catch list like so:

```
(gdb) catch syscall exit exit_group
Catchpoint 2 (syscalls 'exit' [1] 'exit_group' [252])
```

Comment: I'll try building gdb 7 and seeing what it shows. the *& gives the same instruction address: 

<pre>
(gdb) b _exit
Breakpoint 2 at 0x2aeea040f250
(gdb) b *&_exit
Note: breakpoint 2 also set at pc 0x2aeea040f250.
Breakpoint 3 at 0x2aeea040f250
</pre>

<pre>
0x00002aeea040f250 <_exit+0>:   mov    %fs:0x0,%r9
...
0x00002aeea040f275 <_exit+37>:  syscall
</pre>

(Looks like a fairly standard syscall).

I think I've at least isolated the code change that leads to this mysterious exit, just don't understand the details yet.

Comment: Would be better to use `catch syscall exit` and `catch syscall exit_group` instead of numeric values. On my system, for example, `exit` is `[1]` not `[60]`.

Comment: Additionally, you can set both at once with `catch syscall exit exit_group`. In fact, editing it now...

Answer (score 2):

Setting the breakpoint on _exit was a good idea.

You might also try linking statically, just to take a stack of potential gdb complications off the table.

0177 is suspiciously like the *wait status* `wait(2)` returns for *child stopped*, but gdb is printing the *exit status*, which is a different thing, so that's probably a real exit argument.

Comment: OP said he already have breakpoints on _exit and exit. Also, 0177 is 127. How in the world did you get from 127 to SIGCHLD?

Comment: Oh, missed exit. But I'm right about wait status. I'm obviously not talking about the signal number, but the status `wait(2)` returns for a stopped process. Look at this: $ grep IFSTOPPED /usr/include/bits/waitstatus.h  `#define __WIFSTOPPED(status) (((status) & 0xff) == 0x7f)`, AND, `0x7f == 0177`. But I agree that's not what is happening here.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that you have some lazy references unresolved in some shared library loaded into process. I have exactly the same situation that "someone somewhere" exited process and that appeared to be unresolved reference.

**Check your process with "ldd -r" option.**

Looks like ld.so or whatever does lazy resolving of some symbols to uniform exit function (which should be abort IMHO).

My situation:

```
$ ldd ./program
undefined symbol: XXXX  (/usr/lib/libYYY.so)

$./program
program: started! 
...
<program is running regardless of undefined references>
```

Now exit appeared when I've invoked some scenario that used function that was undefined. It always exited with exitcode=127 and gdb reported 0177.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be the case here.  I get no undefined symbols in our executable (not exit nor anything else).