# GDB - how to find out from where program exited

Tags: gdb

While debugging a program in GDB, I get an unexpected "program exited normally". So I'm wondering if is there a way to find out from where (which line) the program exited.

Program is multi-threaded, if that matters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Usually with the command below when the application has finished executing:

```
(gdb) thread apply all bt
```

Of course, if you want to know the exact line you must compile your application with debugging symbols, i.e. `-g`

Comment: That does not print anything for me on GDB 7.7.1.

Answer (score 20):

You could try the GDB command `break exit` to set a breakpoint on the exit(2) library call. If that doesn't get you what you need, maybe `break _exit`. You might need to start your program with 'sta' before getting the latter breakpoint to take. In either case, you should then be able to use the `where` command to get a stack trace showing where you were when the program decided to exit.

Comment: Usually works, but may fail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780765/setting-a-gdb-exit-breakpoint-not-working

Answer (score 5):

Set a breakpoint on _exit and then examine the stack.