# Does QEMU user mode emulation exit in a way that would prevent pthread_join from blocking?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, qemu, system-calls

I'm trying to run QEMU's user mode emulator as a thread in a larger program that I'm writing. I've modified the `linux-user/main.c` file so that the standard `int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp` function is now called `void *qemu_user_mode_func(void *arg)`. I've also added `pthread_exit(NULL)` to the end of that function, as is standard practice for pthreads (or so I've been told).

However, when I try to run a second thread that contains my own test function (shown below in `void *test_func(void *arg)`), the process exits before the second thread completes, even with a call to `pthread_join(`*`tid`*`)`, which I've read blocks the calling thread until thread *`tid`* returns. Does QEMU's user mode emulation exit in such a way that would prevent `pthread_join` from exiting, or am I just using threads wrong?

Here's my code (not including the bulk of `qemu_user_mode_func`):

```
void *qemu_user_mode_func(void *arg)
{
    thread_data_t *thread_data;
    int argc;
    char **argv;
    char **envp;

/** QEMU's normal code **/

    //return 0;
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *test_func(void *arg) {
    struct timespec time;
    time.tv_sec = 7;
    time.tv_nsec = 0;

    nanosleep(&time, NULL);

    printf("hello, world - from a thread\n");
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char**argv, char **envp) {
    //Initialize variables to create thread
    int rc;
    pthread_t threads[2];
    thread_data_t main_args;

    main_args.tid = 1;
    main_args.argc = argc;
    main_args.argv = argv;
    main_args.envp = envp;

    //Create thread
    if ((rc = pthread_create(&(threads[0]), NULL, test_func, NULL))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: pthread_create, rc: %d\n", rc);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if ((rc = pthread_create(&(threads[1]), NULL, qemu_user_mode_func, (void *)&main_args))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: pthread_create, rc: %d\n", rc);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    //Wait for thread to finish, then terminate process
    for (rc = 0; rc < 2; rc++) {
        pthread_join(threads[rc], NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** I've discovered in the `void cpu_loop(CPUX86State *env)` function that when the emulated program reaches its conclusion, QEMU calls syscall 231, which is `sys_exit_group` (as per [1](http://blog.rchapman.org/post/36801038863/linux-system-call-table-for-x86-64)). So I'm guessing this syscall is terminating the entire process that I'm running. I'd appreciate any tips on how to get around that!

Comment: Why don't you just `fork()` and call the qemu main function in the forked child?

Comment: @caf - It has to do with how I'm using qemu - chiefly, I'm working on utilizing the dynamic binary translation system within it, known as the Tiny Code Generator.  I'm trying to begin DBT partway through program execution - as in, a program starts on the native hardware and migrates to the virtual machine partway through execution.  Since the text + data sections of the binary are shared between threads, any memory references to those sections are valid in both threads; all that changes is the stack (which is a whole other beast).  I agree that `fork` is the better solution usually!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by editing the following section in `void cpu_loop(CPUX86State *env)`.  I capture either `sys_exit_group` and `sys_exit` system calls before they are executed, and just return from the function instead.

Original:

```
void cpu_loop(CPUX86State *env)
{
    CPUState *cs = CPU(x86_env_get_cpu(env));
    int trapnr;
    abi_ulong pc;
    target_siginfo_t info;

    for(;;) {
        cpu_exec_start(cs);
        trapnr = cpu_x86_exec(env);
        cpu_exec_end(cs);
        switch(trapnr) {
        case 0x80:
            /* linux syscall from int $0x80 */
            env->regs[R_EAX] = do_syscall(env,
                                          env->regs[R_EAX],
                                          env->regs[R_EBX],
                                          env->regs[R_ECX],
                                          env->regs[R_EDX],
                                          env->regs[R_ESI],
                                          env->regs[R_EDI],
                                          env->regs[R_EBP],
                                          0, 0);
            break;
#ifndef TARGET_ABI32
        case EXCP_SYSCALL:
            /* linux syscall from syscall instruction */
            env->regs[R_EAX] = do_syscall(env,
                                          env->regs[R_EAX],
                                          env->regs[R_EDI],
                                          env->regs[R_ESI],
                                          env->regs[R_EDX],
                                          env->regs[10],
                                          env->regs[8],
                                          env->regs[9],
                                          0, 0);
            break;
#endif
```

Modified:

```
void cpu_loop(CPUX86State *env)
{
    CPUState *cs = CPU(x86_env_get_cpu(env));
    int trapnr;
    abi_ulong pc;
    target_siginfo_t info;

    for(;;) {
        cpu_exec_start(cs);
        trapnr = cpu_x86_exec(env);
        cpu_exec_end(cs);
        switch(trapnr) {
        case 0x80:
            /* linux syscall from int $0x80 */
            env->regs[R_EAX] = do_syscall(env,
                                          env->regs[R_EAX],
                                          env->regs[R_EBX],
                                          env->regs[R_ECX],
                                          env->regs[R_EDX],
                                          env->regs[R_ESI],
                                          env->regs[R_EDI],
                                          env->regs[R_EBP],
                                          0, 0);
            break;
#ifndef TARGET_ABI32
        case EXCP_SYSCALL:
            /* linux syscall from syscall instruction */
----> if ((env->regs[R_EAX] == __NR_exit_group) || (env->regs[R_EAX] == __NR_exit)) {
                return; 
            }
            env->regs[R_EAX] = do_syscall(env,
                                          env->regs[R_EAX],
                                          env->regs[R_EDI],
                                          env->regs[R_ESI],
                                          env->regs[R_EDX],
                                          env->regs[10],
                                          env->regs[8],
                                          env->regs[9],
                                          0, 0);
            break;
#endif
```

Comment: Could you explain the changes that you made so that others can benefit in the future?

Comment: @SevenBits Yup - just edited the solution. Also switched to the original title - it think it captures the essence of the problem better. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

If you turn a complicated preexisting application into thread there are going to be issues.  One is that the application can call `exit` or its variants which will terminate your entire program.  There are numerous other issues that could be causing a problem.  I would suggest using [gdb to determine what is making your program exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376869/gdb-how-to-find-out-from-where-program-exited).

Comment: I'm acutely aware of this haha - unfortunately, no other virtualization program performs (1) dynamic binary translation, and (2) has AARCH64 support (that I'm aware of).  Fortunately, this turned out to have a simple (albeit ugly) fix.