# Setting GDB break point on exit signal

Tags: gdb, breakpoints

I'm trying to set a breakpoint in gdb to stop before an exit(0) signal. I've tried:

```
stop sigquit
```

although the program still exits without stopping. How do I set a breakpoint for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [GDB - how to find out from where program exited](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376869/gdb-how-to-find-out-from-where-program-exited)

Comment: `exit` generates not signals, it is a system call.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you tried setting breakpoints on `exit` or `_exit`?

If that doesn't work have a look at [setting a gdb exit breakpoint not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780765/setting-a-gdb-exit-breakpoint-not-working)